# Glassfish V3 Thread count increase

Tags: multithreading, count, glassfish

I am using spring to manage threads in the Glassfish and below is the code I use. For some reason, 100's of threads are getting created even though I have set the thread pool max count as 10.

```
final WorkManagerTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new WorkManagerTaskExecutor();
final QPRunable runable = new QPRunable(); => this class implements Runnable
taskExecutor.setWorkManagerName("Workmanager1");
taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
taskExecutor.setBlockUntilCompleted(false);
taskExecutor.execute(runnable);
```

Any suggestions about how to make the pool reuse the threads and why the thread count is increasing so much.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spring's docs read:

> On JBoss and GlassFish, obtaining the default JCA WorkManager requires special lookup steps. See the JBossWorkManagerTaskExecutor GlassFishWorkManagerTaskExecutor classes which are the direct equivalent of this generic JCA adapter class.

Maybe that's an issue here?